# Can the text content of an element be read in Angular without reading from the DOM?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-directive

I need to be able to use translated strings in code in my Angular application, but with the i18n tools not yet up to the task, I implemented a slightly hacky version that takes advantage of Angular's existing i18n capabilities, with the intention of phasing out my solution for native Angular as its i18n capabilities catch up to my needs (should be a [5.x release](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477), fingers crossed).

Basically, I have a `TranslationDirective` that reads text from the DOM, and emits events when the text changes:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[myAppTranslation]'
})
export class TranslationDirective implements AfterViewChecked, OnChanges {
  /**
   * dependencies takes an array of the values needed to calculate the output translation
   * we use this for change detection, to minimize the DOM interaction to only when it is necessary
   */
  @Input() dependencies: any[];
  isDirty = true;
  @Input() messageKey: string;
  message: string;
  @Output() messageUpdated = new EventEmitter<TranslationEvent>();

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

  /**
   * sets the translated message and triggers the TranslationEvent
   */
  setMessage() {
    const message = (this.el.nativeElement.textContent || '').trim();
    const oldMessage = (this.message || '');
    if (oldMessage !== message) {
      this.message = message;
      this.isDirty = false;
      this.triggerTranslationEvent();
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.isDirty = true;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.isDirty) {
      this.setMessage();
    }
  }

  /**
   * triggers the messageUpdated EventEmitter with the TranslationEvent
   */
  triggerTranslationEvent() {
    // need to delay a tick so Angular doesn't throw an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
    setTimeout(() => {
      const event = new TranslationEvent(this.messageKey, this.message);
      this.messageUpdated.emit(event);
    });
  }
}

export class TranslationEvent {
  constructor(public messageKey: string, public message: string) {}
}
```

which gets used like this:

```html
<span
  myAppTranslation
  i18n
  [dependencies]="[today]"
  [messageKey]="todaysDateKey"
  (messageUpdated)="setTodaysDateTranslation($event)"
>
  Today is {{today | date:'short'}}
</span>
```

Since the strings to be translated all reside in the templates, Angular's xi18n tool reads them just fine, and the Angular compiler will replace them with the translated strings.

This is functional, but its not great. I suspect that there is a timing bug just waiting to bite me that just hasn't manifested yet. There is an inefficient and slow write-to-DOM-read-from-DOM cycle that would be really nice to eliminate.

I'd like to be able to eliminate one source of problems by bypassing the DOM if I can at all avoid it. Does Angular keep an in-memory copy of the contents of an element that is accessible without going through the DOM? If that's possible, can I avoid writing the translation element to the DOM entirely?

Comment: What about using the ngModel? and please provide plunker link

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a lot of your complexity is because you want to support dynamic text - that the text might change at run-time. I don't think you need to do that, because i18n text needs to be static so that:

1. It can be extracted at compile-time.
2. It can be translated in advance, and you have all the translations stored at a later compile-time.

Your example "Today is ..." is a perfect example of untranslatable text. :-) You should change it to just have "Today is" be a text chunk by itself, and then have the date displayed with the current locale *outside of* that span.

Comment: Angular's i18n tools support translations in that format. The need comes from a 3rd party library that expects text to be passed in via configuration objects, and I need that text to be translated.

Comment: Wow, my bad, I didn't know the Angular i18n tool could handle that. However, you used double-{}'s, so doesn't that make the expression be dynamically evaluated by Angular, before your myAppTranslation directive is called?

Comment: Yes, it will be evaluated before the directive is called - that is part of the point. The example use case includes a date that needs to be localized. Appending the date to a translated string is not an option because the translation can move the location of the date within the string for different languages.